# Find a $m$ divides the area under and above x-axis of $y=x (1 - x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis

My questions is, suppose that for specific $m$, $y=mx$ divides the area under and above $x$-axis of $y=x(1- x)$ into $2$ equal areas, so what is $m$? In an interval, I estimated fast with $m \in (\frac{1}{5}, \frac{2}{5}]$, is this right? I plot this equation on graphs, and only estimated it. I didn't calculate integral precisely.

Comment: Are you familiar with integrals, derivatives?

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to understand the question. What do you mean by 'the area under and above $x$-axis of $y=x(1-x)$'?

Comment: My English is not very good, sorry is hard to understand. I want to say is  there a line, $y=x$, $y=2x$, $y=0.5x$, etc., in general $y=mx$, $n \in \mathbb{R}$, dividing the area of $y=x(1-x)$ into below and above x-axis with the same area. It's hard to explain not with graph.

Comment: @苏景轩 Not a problem, I thought your english was fine. I was wondering more which area you were talking about, I’m assuming the finite area between $x=0$ and $x=1$ right? In which case I’m going to assume you already got the answer you were looking for :)

Comment: Yes, I find the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find the area of $x(1-x)$ from $0$ to $1$ (which is the area above the x axis) which comes out to be $\frac{1}{6}$, now the area between the line $y=mx$ and $y=x(1-x)$ would be $\frac{1}{12}$, so $$\int_0^{1-m}\left[x(1-x)-mx\right]dx=\frac{1}{12}$$
So, $$\frac{(1-m)^2}{2}-\frac{(1-m)^3}{3}-\frac{m(1-m)^2}{2}=\frac{1}{12}$$
$$\frac{m^2-2m+1}{2}+\frac{m^3-3m^2+3m-1}{3}-\frac{m^3-2m^2+m}{2}=\frac{1}{12}$$
$$3m^2-6m+3+2m^3-6m^2+6m-2-3m^3+6m^2-3m=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$-m^3+3m^2-3m+1=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$(1-m)^3=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$m=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$$